# Can steam make one Fleishigs?

Tags: cooking-bishul, water, meat-and-milk

If I go and lean my head over a pot on the stove, open my mouth wide, allow the steam that's rising to enter my mouth, and then swallow it (don't try this at home), does that give me a status of being Fleishigs (i.e. so that I cannot eat dairy for the next 6 hours)?

More importantly, why or why not?

[oh and I suppose the same question would apply to dairy steam as well]

Comment: No time to post an answer now. For starters, consider taking a look [here](http://www.spolter.net/shiurim/hoh/kashrus/HOH%20Kitchen%207%20-%20Reiach%20and%20Ovens.pdf) [pages 4-6], here: www.vbm-torah.org/archive/kashrut/22ovens1.rtf, and here: www.vbm-torah.org/archive/kashrut/23ovens2.rtf.

Comment: To your last point, dairy steam will not make you fleishig.

Comment: Steam into food gives flavor,but steam alone is not food.

Answer (score 4):

Rav Moshe has a Teshuva [YD 2:26](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=33)  regarding taking a vitamin which has meat. Someone asked him if one become fleishigs afterwards?

He answers that one is not since one is prohibited from eating milk after meat for one of two reasons

1. Taste stays in the mouth for six hours.
2. Food stays in teeth.

In this case one doesn't become fleishigs as steam is not achila (eating) and does not have either of the two issues.

Comment: But meat steam does have taste, at least enough to be of concern for making other things fleishig (or "treifing up" a dairy dish (and the reverse for dairy).

Comment: Correct steam can provide taste to other food but plain steam into ones mouth(not food)is not eating.

Comment: See badi hashulchan 16 about placing meat in mouth and then spitting it out and Aruch hashulchan On chewing meat and not eating it.

Comment: You mean [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&pgnum=42)?

Comment: That's the wrong one ,I will find right one.

Comment: http://HebrewBooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=33

Comment: @sam - Where can I find the YD Badei HaShulchan online?

Comment: I don't think there is online.