# Does eating a parev item cooked in an oven with meat make you meaty?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk

If I cook (e.g.) roasted vegetables in an oven whilst at the same time cooking a chicken in a different shelf, would eating the roasted vegetables render me meaty?

There are several factors that need to be considered (see [this article](http://www.torahmusings.com/2012/08/meat-and-dairy-in-one-oven/) for a more in depth analysis) e.g. intention, whether there is liquid/steam/aroma, ventilation, cleanliness of the oven, etc.

There are cases where it would and those that would not make you meaty. I am interested in answers that include both possibilities.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/can-steam-make-one-fleishigs

Comment: I can't access your link at this time. See this link - http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-kosher-cons-handbk.htm as it may provide further insight. I apologize if it tells you the same info that you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lechatchila* (before the fact) it is not permitted to cook in the same oven and at the same time meat and milk dishes (see [SA YD 108:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.108.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). A key issue is one of steam (*zeiah*, for details see [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/08/meat-and-dairy-in-one-oven/) and [there](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/cooking-milk-and-meat-in-one-oven-by-rabbi-howard-jachter)) which carries meat/milk flavor into other dishes. Indeed no opinion permits cooking open milk and meat dishes together in the same oven.

As such the vegetables in your question are considered *basari* and cannot be eaten together with milk. The simple solution however is to double-wrap one of the dishes (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92369/11501) for more details) after which there is no more issue.

However, in the case of parve items who became *basari* through *zeia*, a majority of *poskim* (amongst which the Chida, Kaf HaChayim, Ben Ish Hai, Maharsham) allow eating *halavi* items afterwards without a waiting period with *kinuach ve’hadacha* (cleaning out one’s mouth and rinsing, e.g., through eating a bit of bread and drinking water or other drinks).

**Therefore, to answer your question, these vegetables don't make you *basari* as long as you perform *kinuach ve’hadacha* after eating them.**

Sources: after researching your question, I discussed it with R Binyamin Tabady who wrote up an answer in Hebrew ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0jmA.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlNGA.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8zj7.jpg)) from which I took the above.