# Will parve item remain so within a fume-proof vessel heated inside a meat stove?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I'm laying out my kitchen for kosher and have decided to make my stove and oven all meat. I'll have a separate nook for cooking dairy.

The problem is baking hallah.  Normally that is a parve recipe.  Obviously baking it in a meat oven would render it meat.  Could I protect my hallah as it bakes by  enclosing it in a Dutch oven or other nominally air or fume tight vessel?

Comment: "Obviously baking it in a meat oven would render it meat." Why is this so obvious?

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2012/08/meat-and-dairy-in-one-oven/ There are lots of opinions out there about ovens and flavor transfer. Until we know what framework you are working in, I don't know how this is answerable. (For instance, you probably don't want an answer that says ovens never transfer flavor to bread, or something like that.) Accordingly, I'm going to put this on hold until you [edit] to clarify.

Comment: [According to Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/kosher-appliances/473/oven-kashrus-for-everyday-use-2/), you can bake (as opposed to cook; see article for distinction) an uncovered _parve_ or even _dairy_ item in a meat oven with no problem. Going by that ruling, you wouldn't even need any kind of fume-proof vessel. Your _challah_ would remain _parve_.

Comment: You can see the ruling of the Shulchan Aruch YD 95:1-2 that the item would indeed remain Pareve. The Rema argues that the oven needs to have not cooked a said meat or dairy specific item in the past 24 hours to be permissible. But either way, you have maaany opinions to rely upon

Comment: related: [Does eating a parev item cooked in an oven with meat make you meaty?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59998/does-eating-a-parev-item-cooked-in-an-oven-with-meat-make-you-meaty) - in your case you are not even cooking with meat at the same time so it indeed remains parve if the oven was clean and not used with meat 24 hours beforehand