# Can one oven be used for both meat and milk?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Is it kosher to use one oven for both meat and milk dishes cooked separately. For instance, can I cook a meat dish and, after it's done, put in a milk dish and cook that?

Or does the oven have to be either meat or milk permanently?

Comment: There are so many details which matter. Are you asking about one-time or regularly? After the fact or a prior? Do you mean to use the oven and clean it in between or right away?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104555/ . Here's [another article](http://www.spolter.net/shiurim/HOH/Kashrus/HOH%20Kitchen%207%20-%20Reiach%20and%20Ovens.pdf) on the topic. See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59998/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73093/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14869/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not ideal but is the reality for some. There are plenty of discussions by distinguished authors on the halachic perspectives (e.g., R Doniel Neustadt [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5771-shavuos/), OU Kosher [here](https://oukosher.org/publications/milchigs-and-fleishigs-in-the-oven/), R Michael Broyde [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/08/meat-and-dairy-in-one-oven/) and R Chaim Jachter [here](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/cooking-milk-and-meat-in-one-oven-by-rabbi-howard-jachter)) but, in practice, the following two answers give you practical guidelines

From [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/685085/jewish/How-do-I-Bake-Dairy-if-I-Only-Have-a-Meat-Oven.htm)

> How do I bake dairy as the oven is mainly used for meat?
>
> It's pretty simple. Any dairy you bake in that oven has to be wrapped
> in a double layer. Aluminum foil is great. Make sure each wrapping is
> complete, covers the food entirely, and goes all the way around the
> entire pan or pot—not just the opening. The food and your oven will
> both be completely kosher.

A more complete answer from [aish.com](https://aish.com/single-oven-meat-milk-and-pareve/)

> The best, if possible, would be to have two separate ovens – or a
> double-chambered oven – one for meat and one for dairy, since mix-ups
> are so common. However, if this isn’t possible for you, it’s fine to
> use a single oven for both types, so long as you observe the following
> guidelines:
>
> (a) You should determine which type of food you cook most often,
> whether meat or dairy. That type you can cook as normal in both
> covered and uncovered pots and pans.
>
> (b) The opposite type should only be cooked in a covered pan or pot.
> If the opposite type is completely dry, then there is no need to cover
> it (but the other requirements below do apply).
>
> (c) Separate racks should be used for meat and for dairy (or a layer
> of aluminum foil should be placed on the rack underneath the
> opposite-type pan).
>
> (d) The oven should be cleaned out from any liquidy spills of gravy or
> grease in between uses of meat and dairy.
>
> In terms of pareve, that may be cooked as regular in an oven, even on
> the same racks, with the following restrictions. (For simplicity, I
> assume the oven is regularly used for meat.)
>
> (a) The oven must be clean of any meaty spills. If the oven was not
> checked and cleaned beforehand, the pareve may not be eaten together
> with dairy, but it may be eaten immediately before or after (even in
> the same meal, but the hands should be washed before switching).
>
> (b) Even if the oven is clean, if it was used to cook liquidy
> uncovered meat within the past 24 hours and the pareve is also liquidy
> and uncovered, then it may not be eaten together with dairy but can be
> right before or after.
>
> (c) If the oven is clean and has not been used within 24 hours with
> liquidy uncovered meat, liquidy pareve foods should not be cooked in
> it in order to eat them together with dairy, but if they were cooked,
> they may be eaten together with dairy.
>
> Note that Sephardic Jews are more lenient with such indirect tastes of
> meat and milk (based on Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 95:1-2). Thus, they may
> bake pareve foods in a dairy/meaty oven without restriction and the
> food is still considered pareve.
>
> (Sources: Igrot Moshe Y.D. I 59, Yabia Omer Y.D. V 7, Yalkut Yosef
> 89:35, The Laws of Kashrus by R. B. Forst pp. 226-228.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, if you take the right precautions.  The exact parameters are going to depend on which posek you ask, but [this](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/3704/oven-kashrus-101-using-the-same-oven-for-meat-dairy-fish-pareve/) is the Star K's recommendation.

Comment: Could you please edit to summarize the Star-K's recommendation here?