# What sources discuss whether a pareve dish can be used in the same oven as meat and/or dairy consecutively?

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk

Suppose a pie dish was used only for making fruit pie, and has never contained any dairy or meat.

Suppose it spends time cooking inside an oven that also contained chicken and meat.

The question is, can such a dish be put in an oven in which dairy (i.e. lasagna) is also being cooked?

What does Shulchan Aruch explain about this case. I understand that a specific real case should be brought to a LOR if there is a practical real question to be decided.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question will be closed but I'm pretty certain the rabbonim at dinonline have answered this exact question or one pretty similar to it: http://dinonline.org/tag/milk-and-meat/

Comment: I was taught according to Rambam milk and meat can even cook in the same oven at the same time and uncovered, as long as there's no cross splattering.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for sources.
See Yoreh Deah 95. Responsa Maharsham vol 3 si 208. Igros Moshe YD vol 1 si 40 and Minchas Yitzchak vol 5 si 20 see also Badei Hashulchan si 92 s 8 in biurim.

Comment: Can you summarize the sources for those who don't have access or aren't able to personally parse them?

Answer (score 0):

When placed in the oven with meat, the worst that can happen (assuming there was liquid with the meat and it is uncovered) is that the pot absorbed meat flavor. This doesn't render the dish meaty but you cannot eat it together with milk *a priori* - however you can eat milk afterwards without waiting six hours.

**The pot however doesn't become meaty.** Therefore one can place this (still parve) pot in a dairy oven with lasagna.

Since there are permutations of these cases, it is important to ask a rav.

For sources, see details in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98856/11501).

Comment: One point which is not addressed, neither by your comment or by the post in your link, in regarding the cleanliness of the racks. If a pie dish was put down on a rack which had meaty residue on it, that would make the pot meaty and it would be a big problem to cook it with lasagna. Likewise if residue from the chicken itself could get on the pie dish (i.e gravy splashed out, or the outside of the pot was dirty and the pots touched) it would be a problem.

Comment: @Binyomin The amount of gravy that adheres to an oven rack is almost certainly less than 60x the volume of the next dish you put there.