# Pareve Food and Dairy Cake in the Oven

Tags: kashrut-kosher

If one were to bake a pareve food (on meat pans) in the oven, and there was also a dairy cake in the oven as well (though not touching any pans and on a different shelf), would all the food be treif? Would it matter if it were be d'ieved or l'chatchila?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should check these issues with a Rav since small details can make a big difference. This being said, I don't see the issue. If the meat pan wasn't used for 24 hours, even the parve food cooked there doesn't attain the status of "meaty". Even if the meat pan was used in the last 24 hours, the fact there is no touching reduces risks significantly. There is an issue of *zeia* (steam) if one of the dishes was liquid (one of the questions a Rav would ask) which you do not indicate here (see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98856/11501 for more details on the latter)

Comment: In general, please do not believe strangers on the Internet, use what you learn here to ask questions the right way to a Rav, bringing him all relevant facts (e.g., whether the pan was used for 24 hours and whether one of the dish was liquid)