# How long is one Fleishig after eating something cooked with meat

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, time, meat-and-milk, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, how long is one fleishing after consuming something that is typically pareve cooked with meat? For example, if someone ate vegetables that were cooked in a beef soup, are they fleishing as long as they normally would be if they ate beef?

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59998/does-eating-a-parev-item-cooked-in-an-oven-with-meat-make-you-meaty)

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Not necessarily a dupe. One could reasonably be more meikil there, when the only issue is one of possible zei'ah, than this case, rather than here which would could very well be a case of tavshil shel basar where the Rema is machmir.

Comment: @JoelK but how much is the rama machmir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two relevant debates here. 1) How long must one wait when one is meaty? 2) Do vegetables cooked with meat make you meaty?

For 1, generally speaking the Spanish Rishonim held you have to wait about 6 hours while the Ashkenazi Rishonim and the Geonim held you have to wait much less (let's say an hour). Rama (YD 89:1) rules like the latter opinion but opines that it is proper to be strict for the former opinion.

For 2, nearly all Rishonim hold you need not wait in that case, with Rashbam (who was in the lenient group above) and maybe one or two others ruling you do need to wait. Rama (YD 89:3) notes the custom is to be strict here and wait after such vegetables.

Now the key question: did Rama advocate combining the two stringencies or did he think it sufficient to be strict for 6 hours in the main case of eating actual meat? After all, when you put it together no one ever held of waiting 6 hours after vegetables cooked with meat.

R' Yaakov Emden ([Migdal Oz 3:12](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30778&st=&pgnum=332)) seems to indicate that indeed the binding custom of waiting after such vegetables remained just one hour, while he notes earlier that the custom after actual meat had become 6 hours. R' Akiva Eiger (YD 89:1) similarly views Rama's suggested stringency of 6 hours as limited to the paradigmatic case of eating meat when there aren't mitigating factors.

Pri Megadim ([MZ 89:1](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4483)) however contends that the custom is to be strict in all possible cases to wait a full 6 hours, even when there is no good reason.

Comment: Given how many rishonim took the gemara at face value that waiting doesn't apply to poultry, it's not a stretch to use this sort of logic there too.