# Is chicken collagen considered fleishig or parve?

Tags: medicine, meat-and-milk

I have seen a few brands of Type 2 collagen in a pill form contain [chicken collagen](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-714-collagen%20type%20ii.aspx?activeingredientid=714&activeingredientname=collagen%20type%20ii). Regarding taking pills, I have asked 2 local rabbanim who agreed with this general rule:

Preferably, one should take a pill having kosher ingredients. If one cannot find a pill with kosher ingredients, and taking the pill is necessary for a life-threatening condition, one may take a non-kosher-ingredient pill.

I have also understood that only kosher meat comes under the category of "fleishig" with regard to having to wait after eating it and eating dairy. If one ate non-kosher meat, it is not considered fleishig. (I don't recall where exactly I had heard this; probably in my yeshiva many years ago.)

My questions - Does the above rule apply to taking pills, assuming it was kosher chicken collagen? Does it make a difference if the pill has a flavor and is chewable or not? (I.e. - are the rules of "fleishig" applicable in non-*achila* cases?)Does it matter if the amount of collagen is less than 1/60 in proportion?

Comment: Your pill is for a disease or not really a medicine?

Comment: "I have also understood that only kosher meat comes under the category of "fleishig" with regard to having to wait after eating it and eating dairy" where are you understand this?

Comment: @kouty If you read the info in the link, type 2 collagen is often used for joint health. Many doctors recommend it for people that have osteoarthritis. For 2nd, recall hearing it from a rebbe when I was in yeshiva. If incorrect, please educate me.

Comment: @DanF Asking about that first seems like a better way of approaching this issue than just assuming some vague memory is accurate

Comment: Possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10023

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22900/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10710/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16028/759

Comment: May be that in this topic you can find an answer for a part of your questions:
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68495/9215